# Is there any function or program to play sound after user kills the app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an alarm app made in flutter where I set an alarm and it triggers on time but the problem is when user kills the app the alarm sound stops I did not want that.
I want it like when user kills the app, app stills plays the sound and when user press a button or do some activity then sound stops.
I am using android alarm manager plugin to set alarm.
can anyone help ??
thanks in advance

Comment: The whole point of killing an app is to stop it from running. If an app was able to play sound even after it was killed, that would mean it would be immune to the user's attempts to close it which would come with massive security implications.

Comment: What you are saying is right. But it's an alarm app and work of an alarm is to wake the person. So, if the person kills the app and alarm(sound) stops than it's not helpfull to the user. That's why i am asking this question so, if user kills the app and alarm(sound) doesn't stop then it's helpfull because user gets uncomfortable and user gets up to do what he/she set the alarm for??

Comment: Then what you are asking for is how to write a background service, not an app. Flutter doesn't do background services. You would need to write the service part in native code and then write a platform channel for the Flutter code to be able to communicate with the service.

Comment: @Abion47 Now you got it what i am asking for. I know what to do but i don't know how to do it that's the problem. That's why i came here for the help.

Comment: I would recommend asking a different question targeting what you actually need because your question is tagged Flutter/Dart and you cannot do what you want with Flutter/Dart. Better yet, now that you know what to search for, there exist resources already for learning how to make mobile background services.